# making a skip button that scrolls to the next heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use buttons that have a class called "skiper"
then make clicking that button scroll the window to the next heading element. I don't want to have to write where I want it to go every time.

So far I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".skiper").click(function () {
        $('body').scrollTop($(nextInDOM(this, $('h'))));
        event.preventDefault();
    });     
});
```

And I guess this is completely wrong.

I'm using two plugins: [next-in-dom](http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/) and [scrollTo](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: You are searching for the next `<h>` DOM element. If it is a css class you should use `$(".h")` instead..

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $('body');
    var headings = $('h1');
    var current = 0;

    $(".skipper").click(function (event) {
        ++current;

        if (headings.length > current) {
            body.animate( { scrollTop: headings.eq(current).position().top }, 200);
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Try the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YqKTZ/

You may adjust the selector for the `headings` to your needs. But the JavaScript doesn't have to re-query every time a user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".skiper").click(function (event) {
        $('html, body').scrollTop($(this).nextInDOM($('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')).position().top);
        event.preventDefault();
    });     
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjUhK/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/kjUhK/show)